CCNA Collision Domain can someone explain me
I started recently learning for the CCNA and today I learned about Collision and Broadcast Domains.
As far as what i understood all devices connected to the hub share single collision domain and switch creates separate collision domain for each port.
Broadcast Domain is part of the network where devices can receive broadcasts from another devices within the same network.They can be divided using routers because broadcasts can't pass routers
In this screenshot can someone explain me why is there a collision domain between routers and switches and in which cases is this so? I am really need your help guys and please with thoroughly explanation.Thank you in advance
